# Issue with some CSS being ignored and no scroll bar showing on a single website page

Tags: html, css, flash, swfobject

I have a website that has 10 pages. It's all pretty basic.

I have a page that uses `swfobject.embedSWF` and on this page I have 2 strange issues:

1. CSS regarding navbar spacing is ignored.
2. No scroll bar is shown. For example the only way that the user can scroll down is by doing a two finger swipe down on their touch pad.

Would the `swfobject.embedSWF` cause such problems?

All pages are laid out exactly the same, the only thing that is different on them is the paragraph content, but on this certain page I use `swfobject.embedSWF`.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: add a link to your page please